# how to expend link area- hit using css code

Tags: css

I have a site built in Joomla
I'm having a problem with my sub menu links,
I want to expend the hit area using css (like this option in a flash button)
Is that possible?
this is my code now:
(collection is the main button that open sub menu with the links I'm having problem)

```
#collections {
display:block;
margin:20px 0 180px 30px;
}
#collections ul {
 margin: 0;

 list-style:none;
 }
#collections ul li{
 display:inline;
 padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #6cabe7;

}
#collections ul.menu li a span{
 color: #543019;
}
#collections ul.menu li.active a span{
 color: #6cabe7;
}
#collections ul li a:link, #collections ul li a:visited {
 color: #6cabe7;
 text-decoration:none;
}
#collections ul li a:hover {
 color: #6cabe7;
}
#collections .moduletable h3 {
 color: #6cabe7;
 font-size:16px;
 margin-bottom:9px;
}
```

What to do?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather telepathic response.

```
collections ul.menu li a {padding:10px;}
```

**EDIT**

In your case "fading" problem can be solved with

```
collections ul.menu li a {position:relative;z-index:99}
```

But it is quick and dirty. It's better to debug why it happens.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer.. but it doesnt work..this is the link for the site:http://www.talia-designer-clothes.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=49&Itemid=60 . i tried to add the padding but it just expend the gup between the buttons. what can i do?

Comment: the site was built in joomla, im just updating the links but from some reason it seems that the mouse is keep running or fading..i tried to find the html page but i cant find it ...(joomla has many files...)

Comment: well i added this to my css i think its working now:))) thank you very muchhhh.